# typesetting a viscous damping coefficient

Tags: siunitx

I want to typeset a damping coefficient (Force/Velocity) like this

```
c = 100 N/(m/s)
```

or

```
               -1
c = 100 N (m/s)
```

using LaTeX and the `siunitx` package, but I don't know if is it possible to do the kind of grouping I'd like to do.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
% \usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

First method, from @Sebastiano:
\begin{verbatim}
$c=100\, \unit{N \per(\meter\per\second)}$ or $c=\,100 \unit{N (m\per s)^{-1}}$
\end{verbatim}

$c=100\, \unit{N \per(\meter\per\second)}$ or $c=\,100 \unit{N (m\per s)^{-1}}$

\vspace{1ex}
Same, but with the thin space separating the number from the units in the second case corrected:

\begin{verbatim}
$c=100\, \unit{N \per(\meter\per\second)}$ or $c=100 \, \unit{N (m\per s)^{-1}}$
\end{verbatim}

$c=100\, \unit{N \per(\meter\per\second)}$ or $c=100 \, \unit{N (m\per s)^{-1}}$

\vspace{1ex}
Another approach which uses a fractional form.  This wasn't requested by the original poster, but I personally find it more readable:
\begin{verbatim}
$c = \qty{100}{\frac{N}{m/s}}$
\end{verbatim}

$c = \qty{100}{\frac{N}{m/s}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 also for have cited my name :-)

Answer (score 1):

Like how this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
$c=100\, \unit{N \per(\meter\per\second)}$ or $c=\,100 \unit{N (m\per s)^{-1}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]